# How to test packages with Groovy Beta?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to test some of my packages with Groovy Beta under Ubuntu 12.10.

I followed the instructions reported [here](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu), however it seems to be incomplete. Especially, what does mean:

> Make sure you have re-indexed the ROS.org server

I tried to setup the sources list in the following way, however when I type `sudo apt-get install ros-...` it doesn't found any ros package.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu quantal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

I tried to access http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/quantal/main and the distros seems to be there.

How can I install Groovy beta?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47068/how-to-test-packages-with-groovy-beta?/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-30**:
The `apt-get update` simply makes sure you have an up to date Debian package index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for that, Ubuntu Groovy Beta has not even been released yet, and the install instructions and packaging for different Ubuntu distributions are still work in progress at this time.

You can try the installation from source linke on this page, but please take not that the pages are work in progress (I'll add that to the wiki) and may not work for you.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1